# OSGi uses constraint violation

Tags: maven, osgi, bundle, fuseesb, jbossfuse

I try to start my bundle created by Maven in FUSE ESB OSGi container. But I got error with its three dependencies:

```
1. libthrift-0.7.0.jar
2. httpclient-4.0.1.jar
3. httpcore-4.0.1.jar

Error executing command: Error starting bundles:
Unable to start bundle 262: Uses constraint violation. Unable to resolve bundle 
revision file__opt_FuseESBEnterprise-7.1.0_deploy_libthrift-0.7.0.jar [316.0]
because it is exposed to package 'org.apache.http' from bundle revisions 
org.apache.httpcomponents.httpcore [291.0] and org.apache.httpcomponents.httpclient     
[290.0] via two dependency chains.

Chain 1:
 file__opt_FuseESBEnterprise-7.1.0_deploy_libthrift-0.7.0.jar [316.0]
import: (osgi.wiring.package=org.apache.http)
 |
export: osgi.wiring.package=org.apache.http
org.apache.httpcomponents.httpcore [291.0]

Chain 2:
file__opt_FuseESBEnterprise-7.1.0_deploy_libthrift-0.7.0.jar [316.0]
import: (osgi.wiring.package=org.apache.http.client)
 |
export: osgi.wiring.package=org.apache.http.client; uses:=org.apache.http
export: osgi.wiring.package=org.apache.http
org.apache.httpcomponents.httpclient [290.0]
```

Can anyone explain to me what is this error about?

Comment: Read my blog post for an explanation of "uses constraints" in OSGi: http://njbartlett.name/2011/02/09/uses-constraints.html

Comment: Thanks for your post Neil. Now I figure out the problem is `apache.http` which like `ulti.verify` illustrated in your example. In your post, you give the solution by remove the duplication. But I am wondering how to remove it. By changing the export in the manifest?

Answer (score 2):

How did you install the http core and client bundles?

You can try installing camel-http4 as a feature as it provides the http client out of the box.

```
features:install camel-http4
```

And then afterwards just install your own bundle.